# Why G-d didn't give Adam time/chance to repent?

Tags: sin, repentance-teshuvah, adam

If I understand the Midrash and the verses correctly, G-d judged Adam straight away after he sinned and expelled them from Eden (see [Avos dR"N 1,8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Avot_D'Rabbi_Natan.1.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> ...תשיעית הכניסו לגן עדן.
>   עשירית צוהו.
>   אחד עשר סרח.
>   שתים עשר נטרד והלך לו

Why Adam wasn't given a chance/time to repent and spare the rest of the history maybe till the end of the day or a week or a month?

Comment: If the expulsion were the punishment, I might agree, but the expulsion (to my mind) was a natural consequence of the change in man's nature. He could not stay in the garden because of who he now was.

Comment: @rosends How bout אֶל־הָאִשָּׁה אָמַר הַרְבָּה אַרְבֶּה עִצְּבוֹנֵךְ וְהֵרֹנֵךְ בְּעֶצֶב תֵּלְדִי בָנִים וְאֶל־אִישֵׁךְ תְּשׁוּקָתֵךְ וְהוּא יִמְשָׁל־בָּךְ׃ or אֲרוּרָה הָאֲדָמָה בַּעֲבוּרֶךָ בְּעִצָּבוֹן תֹּאכֲלֶנָּה כֹּל יְמֵי חַיֶּיךָ

Comment: @rosends The posuk says "וַיְגָרֶשׁ אֶת־הָאָדָם" - it doesn't sound natural to me.

Comment: I would shift the question away from "expel" and just to the stated punishment. And being chased out doesn't change that it was a natural consequence.

Comment: @rosends וְעַתָּה פֶּן-יִשְׁלַח יָדוֹ, וְלָקַח גַּם מֵעֵץ הַחַיִּים, וְאָכַל, וָחַי לְעֹלָם doesn't sound like a punishment at all!

Comment: I think it's implied that Adam had time to repent when God asks him "what did you do?" He responded by blaming Chava.

Comment: @DanF It all happened in 1-2- hours on רה"ש - why not give them רה"ש to repent, for example.