# Why Dor Hamidbar weren't given a chance to repent?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, repentance-teshuvah, dor-hamidbar

This probably echoes "[why-G-d-didnt-give-adam-chance-to-repent](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/102155/why-g-d-didnt-give-adam-time-chance-to-repent)".

I'm trying to empathize Dor Hamidbar and try to imagine how would they feel, doomed by G-d Himself to die pointlessly in the wilderness in the next [tens of] years without parole. That must have been harsh! ([Num 17,29](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.14.29?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)):

> **בַּמִּדְבָּר הַזֶּה יִפְּלוּ פִגְרֵיכֶם** וְכָל־פְּקֻדֵיכֶם לְכָל־מִסְפַּרְכֶם מִבֶּן עֶשְׂרִים שָׁנָה וָמָעְלָה אֲשֶׁר הֲלִינֹתֶם עָלָי׃
>
> **In this very wilderness shall your carcasses drop**. Of all of you who were recorded in your various lists from the age of twenty years up, you who have muttered against Me,

Why didn't all benevolent and merciful G-d give them a chance to repent?

Comment: They had been given nine previous chances to repent... Eventually enough is enough

Comment: @JoelK Where does it say that if you "שבע יפול צדיק" you're not getting additional chances. Is G-d that limited?

Comment: Maybe if they would have done Teshuva HaShem would have treated them differently. According to some the Midbar was a miraculous place where they spent the great majority of their time involved in spiritual pursuits, there’s was no work or gashmius so it’s not like they lived a miserable existence

Comment: @Lages after you're doomed to die any moment for 40 years? Would you enjoy such living?

Comment: Remember that one explanation for Hashem "hardening Pharaoh's heart" is that there is indeed no *tshuva* possible after a while

Comment: @Al Berko with all due respect aren’t we all doomed to die at any moment? Yet we all find a way to enjoy living

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Of course they had the chance to repent. Everyone does, as long as they are alive. You seem to be assuming that a "chance to repent" means that all the consequences go away, which is not true.

Answer (score 3):

For some sins,  repentance is just not enough (Rambam Tshuva 1,4)

> עבר על מצות לא תעשה שאין בה כרת ולא מיתת בית דין ועשה תשובה, תשובה תולה ויום הכפורים מכפר
>
> If he did Karet or death penalty and repent, repentance and Yom Kippur "hang" the sin, and suffering will complete the redemption, and he will never be fully be forgiven, until suffering will set upon him...

This sin was too severe for repentance only, they had to die **and repent** to be forgiven!!!

Rambam Tshuva 1,4:

> וכן כל מחוייבי מיתות בית דין ומחוייבי מלקות, אין מתכפר להן במיתתן או בלקייתן עד שיעשו תשובה ויתודו.
>
> Death penalty and strikes condemns, are not forgiven for their death or being hit, until they will repent and confess.

Comment: @Everybody I feel that my translation here is not perfect, if someone can do it better, please do.

Comment: Your sources are fine, but I wouldn't say that repentence "is not enough". It's exactly what you are supposed to do. But as you are pointing out, that doesn't mean that all the consequences go away.